# How to print a range of columns in a CSV in AWK?

Tags: bash, awk

With `awk`, I can print any column within a CSV, e.g., this will print the 10th column in `file.csv`.

```
awk -F, '{ print $10 }' file.csv
```

If I need to print columns 5-10, including the comma, I only know this way:

```
awk -F, '{ print $5","$6","$7","$8","$9","$10 }' file.csv
```

This method is not so good if I want to print many columns. Is there a simpler syntax for printing a range of columns in a CSV in `awk`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard way to do this in awk is using a for loop:

```
awk -v s=5 -v e=10 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for (i=s; i<=e; ++i) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<e?OFS:ORS)}' file
```

However, if your delimiter is simple (as in your example), you may prefer to use `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f5-10 file
```

Perl deserves a mention (using `-a` to enable autosplit mode):

```
perl -F, -lane '$"=","; print "@F[4..9]"' file
```

Comment: +1 the above `cut` or `awk` is what I'd really do, the `gensub()` answer I posted is just a cute alternative.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a loop in awk to print columns from 5 to 10:

```
awk -F, '{ for (i=5; i<=10; i++) print $i }' file.csv
```

Keep in mind that using `print` it will print each columns on a new line. If you want to print them on same line using `OFS` then use:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ for (i=5; i<=10; i++) printf("%s%s", $i, OFS) }' file.csv
```

Comment: This adds a trailing comma to the output.

Comment: Yes I mentioned it in my answer also and requirement is not clear if columns after 10th are going to be printed after this print or not.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ cat file
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m
$
$ awk -v s=5 -v n=6 '{ print gensub("(([^,]+,){"s-1"})(([^,]+,){"n-1"}[^,]+).*","\\3","") }' file
e,f,g,h,i,j
```

`s` is the start position and `n` is the number of fields to print from that point on. Or if you prefer to specify start and end:

```
$ awk -v s=5 -v e=10 '{ print gensub("(([^,]+,){"s-1"})(([^,]+,){"e-s"}[^,]+).*","\\3","") }' file
e,f,g,h,i,j
```

Note that this will only work with single-character field separators since it relies on being able to negate the FS in a character class.