# I need to get the first word from a string which is separated by dot in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

for example I have a string Hello.World.Get.book I need only Hello to be printed

Comment: How about google it first ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWK command line printing column separated by comma](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842504/awk-command-line-printing-column-separated-by-comma)

Answer (score 0):

cut -d '.' -f1

will cut fields using '.' as a delimiter