# How to ignore any particular column data from csv file using linux cli?

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, grep, cat

I have 9 column like `c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9` and I want to cat the value of `c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 and c9`.

Columns have following data in CSV format. How can I do this in Linux by CLI? Please help

**Sample data**

```
123,B006195,T,O,INDIVIDUAL,25^5820200^,2018-04-25,13,NEW
12,C06195,T,O,INDIVIDUAL,25^5820200^,2018-04-25,13,NEW
12345,B00619,T,O,IND,25^5820200^,2018-04-25,13,OLD
```

I have tried to use `cat file.csv | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' > newfile`

Comment: Do you want to keep only the values of c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 and c9? and trash the other columns right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract specific columns from delimited file using Awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7857090/608639), [How to print a range of columns in a CSV in AWK?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25461806/608639), [How to extract one column of a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19602181/608639), [Printing column separated by comma using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26842504/608639), etc.

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please provide reason for down votes on answers.

Comment: If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about what you mean by `cat the value of c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 and c9` however if want you want is to filter only those columns, then you can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$9}' sample.csv
```

**INPUT:**

```
more sample.csv 
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9
123,B006195,T,O,INDIVIDUAL,25^5820200^,2018-04-25,13,NEW
12,C06195,T,O,INDIVIDUAL,25^5820200^,2018-04-25,13,NEW
12345,B00619,T,O,IND,25^5820200^,2018-04-25,13,OLD
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$9}' sample.csv 
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c9
123,B006195,T,O,INDIVIDUAL,NEW
12,C06195,T,O,INDIVIDUAL,NEW
12345,B00619,T,O,IND,OLD
```

**Explanations:**

You define as field separator (input,output) a `,` (`BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}`) then you just print for each line the columns that you need to display `{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$9}` after you redirect the output to a new csv file

If you think that `awk` is an overkill for this task than you can also just use the `cut` command (`-d','` is to define a `,` as delimiter and `-f...` is to specify which field need to be kept):

```
$ cut -d',' -f1,2,3,4,5,9 sample.csv
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c9
123,B006195,T,O,INDIVIDUAL,NEW
12,C06195,T,O,INDIVIDUAL,NEW
12345,B00619,T,O,IND,OLD
```

Comment: Thanks, Allan. It's work. I mean cat file_name to get the output of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Following solution may help you on same, you need to provide field numbers in variable of `awk` named `fields` and could print it.

```
awk -F, -v fields="1,2,3,4,5,9" 'BEGIN{num=split(fields, array,",")} {for(i=1;i<=num;i++){printf("%s%s",$array[i],i==num?ORS:OFS)}}' OFS=,   Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F, -v fields="1,2,3,4,5,9" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(fields, array,",")}
{
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    printf("%s%s",$array[i],i==num?ORS:OFS)}}
' OFS=,   Input_file
```

***Explanation of above code:***

```
awk -F, -v fields="1,2,3,4,5,9" '              ##Setting field seprator as comma here with -F. Setting variable named fields with values of fields which we need.
BEGIN{                                         ##Starting BEGIN section here for awk which will be executed before reading the Input_file.
  num=split(fields, array,",")}                ##using split to split the variable fields into array named array and creating variable num which will have number of element of array.
{
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                         ##Starting a for loop here which starts from variable named i value from 1 to till value of variable num.
    printf("%s%s",$array[i],i==num?ORS:OFS)}}  ##Printing value of array[i] and then $array[i] will print the field value in current line too. Then checking condition variable i value equal to variable num then print new line else print space with OFS.
' OFS=,  Input_file                            ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: That's a nice and original solution +1!! ;-)