# How to print $1, $2 and then all remaining parameters together in AWK

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I'm making a script that generates aliases/abbreviations from a base file. The base file structure is something like this:

```
sctl   sudo         systemctl
pac    sudo         pacman
```

This works fine with the following code that reads the base file, removes comments and awks the abbreviation line on the abbreviation file:

```
    sed "s/\s*#.*$//;/^\s*$/d" $command_file | 
    awk -v c=$cmd -v o="$comp" '{ print c" "$1""o"\""$2" "$3"\"" }' >> $file
```

And the end result would be something like this:

```
abbr sctl "sudo systemctl"
abbr pac "sudo pacman"
```

But this code doesn't work when the line has many parts after the 3rd parameter:

```
svu    playerctl    -p spotify volume +0.05
```

How can i go about printing in that format? $1 $2 ($3..$N)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461806/how-to-print-a-range-of-columns-in-a-csv-in-awk

Comment: I don't know how it would apply in this case, since I need to print either alias or abbrev at the start which is the c variable (for zsh or fish) and just after $1 I need to put either " " or "=" (again for fish or zsh) which is the o variable, and also quotes before $2 and after the last parameter.

Comment: you could just get rid of the sed component and run the awk block on lines that don't start with comments / have at least so many fields

Comment: Much easier simply to keep an `aliases` file and source it in your `.bashrc`. Suggestions, create separate blocks that test `if [ "$UID" -eq '0' ]; then alias pms='pacman -S --needed'; alias pmsu='pacman -Syu'; ... else alias pms='sudo pacman -S --needed'; alias pmsu='sudo pacman -Syu'; ... fi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can erase the first two fields and trim the space from the remainder, eg.

```
{ 
  printf "%s %s ", $1, $2
  $1=$2=""; sub(/^\s*/, "", $0);
  printf "\"%s\"\n", $0
}
```

With output like,

```
svu playerctl "-p spotify volume +0.05"
```

Note: the `\s` regex requires gnu awk as pointed out by Ed Morton.

Answer (score 2):

You never need sed when you're using awk. Given this input file:

```
$ cat file
sctl   sudo         systemctl   # here is a comment
        # and here is another
pac    sudo         pacman

svu    playerctl    -p spotify volume +0.05
```

here's what your sed+awk outputs:

```
$ sed "s/\s*#.*$//;/^\s*$/d" file |  awk -v c="abbr" -v o=" " '{ print c" "$1""o"\""$2" "$3"\"" }'
abbr sctl "sudo systemctl"
abbr pac "sudo pacman"
abbr svu "playerctl -p"
```

which you can get just from awk alone:

```
$ awk -v c="abbr" -v o=" " '{sub(/\s*#.*/,"")} NF{print c" "$1""o"\""$2" "$3"\""}' file
abbr sctl "sudo systemctl"
abbr pac "sudo pacman"
abbr svu "playerctl -p"
```

and which you can then adjust to do what you want:

```
$ awk -v c="abbr" -v o=" " '{sub(/\s*#.*/,"")} NF{x=$1; sub(/^\S+\s+/,""); $1=$1; print c, x o "\"" $0 "\""}' file
abbr sctl "sudo systemctl"
abbr pac "sudo pacman"
abbr svu "playerctl -p spotify volume +0.05"
```

or (I can't tell from your question what you want inside/outside of the double quotes):

```
$ awk -v c="abbr" -v o=" " '{sub(/\s*#.*/,"")} NF{x=$1" "$2; sub(/^(\S+\s+){2}/,""); $1=$1; print c, x o "\"" $0 "\""}' file
abbr sctl sudo "systemctl"
abbr pac sudo "pacman"
abbr svu playerctl "-p spotify volume +0.05"
```

The above uses GNU awk for `\s` and `\S` - with other awks use `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]` instead.

Since we're using GNU awk, though, we can do the job more concisely and efficiently with the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk -v c="abbr" -v o=" " '{sub(/\s*#.*/,""); $1=$1} match($0,/(\S+) (.*)/,a){print c, a[1] o "\"" a[2] "\""}' file
abbr sctl "sudo systemctl"
abbr pac "sudo pacman"
abbr svu "playerctl -p spotify volume +0.05"

$ awk -v c="abbr" -v o=" " '{sub(/\s*#.*/,""); $1=$1} match($0,/(\S+ \S+) (.*)/,a){print c, a[1] o "\"" a[2] "\""}' file
abbr sctl sudo "systemctl"
abbr pac sudo "pacman"
abbr svu playerctl "-p spotify volume +0.05"
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this later, thank you for giving me a new perspective, I thought you needed sed to do the comment part. Upvoted =D

Answer (score 1):

Substitute the two extra fields out of existence.

```
$ echo "svu playerctl -p spotify volume +0.05" | gawk '
  { print $1; $1 = ""
    print $2; $2 = ""
    print substr($0,3) } '
svu
playerctl
-p spotify volume +0.05
```

The `substr` removes the output field separators from the remnants of the first two fields.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk (standard Linux - specific to gawk) script that does all the work in one sweep:

```
awk -v c="abbr" -v o=" " '/(^\s*$)|(^\s*#.*$)/ {next}  # discard empty lines and comments
{
    arg3=$0;                          # save current line to arg3 variable
    sub($1" "$2,"",arg3);             # remove $1  and $2 from arg3
    print(c" "$1""o"\""$2" "arg3"\"") # print formated output
}' input.txt
```

input.txt

```
ctl   sudo         systemctl
# comment line
pac    sudo         pacman
   # comment line
demo1  sudo         arg1 arg2 arg3

demo2  sudo         arg4 -arg5 -arg6 456
                         # comment line
```

Output:

```
abbr ctl "sudo          systemctl"
abbr pac "sudo          pacman"
abbr demo1 "sudo          arg1 arg2 arg3"
abbr demo2 "sudo          arg4 -arg5 -arg6 456"
```

Comment: I'm getting premature EOF when i use your approach

Comment: a symptom of unclosed `'` . test your input file `cat input.txt`, add a terminating new line.

Comment: Removed the ending } of the function when deleting the old stuff =P

Comment: thanks, please express your appreciation with an upvote.

Comment: That wouldn't remove comments from the end of a line that has data in it, e.g. something along the lines of `ctl   sudo         systemctl # comment at end of line`. Also avoid writing `sub($1...` as it'll fail when $1 contains RE metachars. use `sub(/\S...` instead (assuming removing $1 is what you want to do and you're using GNU awk for `\S`).

Comment: Thanks, removing comments from end of line was not required. Thanks for the $1 comment, very correct. Following the current questions $1 and $2 are pure alpha.

Comment: Removing comments from end of line wasn't NOT required either :-). The OPs sed script handles comments stand-alone or at the end of lines so if you're handling one.... Yeah, I know the examples are just alphabetic but who knows what else is in the real files and avoiding using input strings in a regexp context (unless you have a very specific need) is a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

Here is  `GNU sed` version:

```
sed -r 's/(^[^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+(.*)/abbr \1 "\2 \3"/g' base_file
abbr sctl "sudo systemctl"
abbr pac "sudo pacman"
abbr svu "playerctl -p spotify volume +0.05"
```

***Explanation:*** Here back-referencing is used, each column is captured into respective groups and later used as `\1`, `\2`,`\3`. Note that `-r` flag is used in above sed command to enable extended regex. If this flag is not available in the target machine, then following command can be used:

```
sed  's/\(^[^ ]\+\)\s\+\([^ ]\+\)\s\+\(.*\)/abbr \1 "\2 \3"/g' base_file
abbr sctl "sudo systemctl"
abbr pac "sudo pacman"
abbr svu "playerctl -p spotify volume +0.05"
```

Only difference in the two commands in that `(` ,`)`,`+` are escaped in the later.