# Insert html tag to particular column in csv file

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, sed

I trying to modify one column in csv file
Csv file looks like

```
"Name", "Gender", "Link"
"Josh", "Male", "https://url.com/josh"
"Samanta", "Female", "https://url.com/samanta"
```

Main task: add Html tag to all links.

Example of how csv should look:

```
"Name", "Gender", "Link"
"Josh", "Male", "<a href="https://url.com/josh"/a>"
"Samanta", "Female", "<a href="https://url.com/samanta"/a>"
```

I do not completely understand how it works in awk or sed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk, here's a solution:

```
cat text.csv | awk 'NR>1 && NF{ OFS=","; print $1 $2 "<a href=\"" $3 "\">" substr($1, 1, length($1)-1) "<a/>" }'
```

`NR>1` - true for line numbers greater than 1.

`NF` - number of fields, 0/false for empty lines.

`OFS=","` - output field separator, splits on comma.

`print` - you can intersperse `$1` variables with `"quoted strings"`

`substr()` - as I used `<a>$1</a>` so the links have a name, I trimmed the trailing comma that awk keeps in the `$1` variable.

Some other similar stackoverflow links on `awk` & `csv`, with suggestions like `cut`:
[extract-specific-columns-from-delimited-file-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857090/extract-specific-columns-from-delimited-file-using-awk), [how-to-print-a-range-of-columns-in-a-csv-in-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461806/how-to-print-a-range-of-columns-in-a-csv-in-awk), [how-to-extract-one-column-of-a-csv-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602181/how-to-extract-one-column-of-a-csv-file)

Comment: Thanks, it almost works. I will need to include quotes next time.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't copy the correct code from my terminal. Try the edited code above :)